# string interpolation for dynamic html attributes in template literals

Tags: javascript, html, jsx, storybook, template-literals

I am currently working on a project using the storybook. This is what I have in mdx file now:

```
export const Template = ({dark, width, height, theme}) => {
  return html`
    <my-button
      @click=${action('button clicked')}
      width="${width}"
      height="${height}"
      theme="${theme}"
      ?dark=${dark}>
    </my-button>
  `;
};
```

In the storybook Code panel, when I set dark to false in Controls, it shows

```
<my-button width="200" height="40" theme="dark"  >
</my-button>
```

which is what I want, but when I set dark to true in Controls, it shows

```
<my-button width="200" height="40" theme="dark" dark="" >
</my-button>
```

What I want is:
when I set dark to true in Controls, it shows

```
<my-button width="200" height="40" theme="dark" dark >
</my-button>
```

I've tried many ways to override this, but none of them works. I feel like it is something auto generated, which won't allow people to override it. Please help me on this.

Comment: ive not used storybook so might be completely wrong. could you not change `?dark=${dark}?` to something like `?${dark?"dark":""}` (possibly without the ?)

Comment: You don't have an attribute, but a property (similar to `disabled` or `required`). So you need to use what ever is appropriate for including that. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with react or story book.

Comment: Why would you not want `dark=""`? It's one of three legitimate usages of *boolean attributes*.

Comment: @connexo It is product requirement, I have no choice

Comment: Can you explain the requirement? Btw, providing presentational attributes on a custom element like `height` and `width` seems like falling back into the dark ages of the web.